# Google app script runs in debug mode, not in run mode

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Hello Google Script experts, I'm new to google script and trying something related to HTTP POST from google docs.

I've a google app script that sends a post request (API) on opening a google doc.

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var actDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docID = actDoc.getId();
  var repeater = 0;
  var data = {
                'bstask':  text,
                'docid': docID
              };
   console.log(data);
   var options = {
         'method' : 'post',
                'contentType': 'application/json',
                // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
                'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
              };
              ui.alert("Sending request with the payload" + data.bstask + " and " + data.docid);
              var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://test.com/path', options);
              ui.alert("Response is: " + response.getResponseCode());
              if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                Logger.log(response.getContentText() + response.getAllHeaders());
                ui.alert('Yey!! Document refreshed.');
              }
              else{
                ui.alert('Opps!! Document refresh failed.'+ response.getContent());
              }
  
}
```

This script is used to provide an option to the user to update the document when it is opened or refreshed. This script runs fine and invoking the API when I test it in debug mode. But, when I want this script to be executed on opening the document, it is not invoking the API and the rest of the UI prompts are working fine. Am I missing something here or something wrong with the script? I really appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple Triggers – Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

> Because simple triggers fire automatically, without asking the user for authorization, they are subject to several restrictions:
>
> - They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the Language service, which is anonymous.

In other words, the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call will not execute when opening the document because it requires authorization. You should be able to see this failure in the execution logs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Diego. What would be the alternative to invoke the API on opening the document?

Comment: @RamuChowdam Consider [installing your trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).